# Need Help in GIT merge

Tags: git, github

Suppose I am having a file with the following content

> **This line I dont want to delete**

Say someone cloned this file and made some changes in it. After the changes the file's content is

> **I deleted the line that you want**
>
> **I added another newline**

Now i want file with the following contents

> **This line I dont want to delete**
>
> **I deleted the line that you want**
>
> **I added another newline**

Is it possible to do this with GIT? If yes please guide me to do that.....

Edit: I have tried git merge.while doing merge we can keep old version or new version but how to mege both the contents.(I want all the contents available in both  files)

Comment: Have you actually **tried** the merge? Git is quite smart about merging, so it may well be that it automatically does what you want. You should try stuff first, and ask when you have an actual problem

Comment: I have tried merging . but I was not able to acheive what I need in the above scenario. Help me if you know instead of giving some common suggestion

Comment: @udi That common suggestion is the norm for this site. Try the obvious first. If you want to "confirm", try it yourself, and then undo it if you don't like the results.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ With out trying that how could I ask a question? Really I am in desperate need of doing this in my project. That is why I asked that question. For you people it may look silly. Sorry for not being an expert.

Comment: @udi I also am far from an expert, for the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do such things manually. You do not want the whole change that the other user made (he deleted your line and inserted two other lines), so how should git know what to do? That is just not possible. Not only with git but with any tool out there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to confirm that it is not possible other than manual processing.

Comment: You want to confirm that? Or you wanted someone else to confirm that? If so how was that done? Neither did you confirm something nor did anybody else here confirm something (because we can not)

Comment: This is not about confirm something. Since I am not an expert I make sure that the operation which I mentioned can not be done by using GIT with the help of some expert user. I got the answer from Argeman. I did not expect this kind of negative comments on my question.

Comment: @udi I don't understand the negative comments, downvotes and the closing of your answer either. It's not a high quality technical question, but still valid. Don't worry too much.